# Sparql query issue with DBpedia retrieving

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to run this Sparql statement to read data from DBpedia; However, it only return the column names and no row data.
If anybody can let me know what's the issue. I'll be more appreciated
Sparql query below:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?actor ?movie ?director ?movie_date
WHERE {
     ?m dc:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films> .
     ?m rdfs:label ?movie .
     FILTER(LANG(?movie) = "en")
     ?m dbp:released ?movie_date .
     FILTER(DATATYPE(?movie_date) = xsd:date)
     ?m dbp:starring ?a .
     ?a rdfs:label ?actor .
     FILTER(LANG(?actor) = "en")
     ?m dbp:director ?d .
     ?d rdfs:label ?director .
     FILTER(LANG(?director) = "en")
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not all the queried triples exist. If at least one of the relations doesnt exist, no result will be given.

So with the `OPTIONAL` keyword, answers will be given only if they exist and wont block your query if they don't. It simply leaves the missing value empty.

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?actor ?movie ?director ?movie_date

WHERE {
 ?m dc:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films> .

 OPTIONAL{
   ?m rdfs:label ?movie .
   FILTER(LANG(?movie) = "en") }

 OPTIONAL {
   ?m dbp:released ?movie_date .
   FILTER(DATATYPE(?movie_date) = xsd:date) }

 OPTIONAL{
   ?m dbp:starring ?a .
   ?a rdfs:label ?actor .
   FILTER(LANG(?actor) = "en") }

 OPTIONAL{
   ?m dbp:director ?d .
   ?d rdfs:label ?director .
   FILTER(LANG(?director) = "en") }
}
```

Comment: If many values are still empty, perhaps should you revise your query.

Comment: If its empty, it simply does not exist.

Comment: No, I retrieved the right data however, there are some cells contain no value and I was trying to remove incomplete records, I just added an extra filter to my query.